# echo specific string inside quotes from variable

Tags: bash, variables, output, echo

I need a script that echo one of strings wrapped in quotes.

For example, from variable `x="C. Ronaldo" "dos Santos Aveiro" "Cristiano Ronaldo"` i want to echo the third one.

So I want to get output like: `"Cristiano Ronaldo"`

I've tried it with `echo $x | awk '{print $3}'` but it gives me `"dos`..

Any help?

Comment: if using a shell that supports arrays, `x=("C. Ronaldo" "dos Santos Aveiro" "Cristiano Ronaldo") ; echo "${x[2]}"` produces `Cristiano Ronaldo` (array indexes are zero-based). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default awk splits records by spaces into fields, given your string, `"dos` is the third field. To parse this string the way you desire GNU awk's `FPAT` is required. E.g:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"' '{print $3}'
```